# Formatting Author Section in Journals

Tags: ieeetran, author, journal

I am making a journal from my research. My uni used an adapted IEEETransaction Journal Template with the **author** section looks like this (this screenshot is generated by Microsoft Word)
[image: sample expected output]

Currently, I am only given this template by my uni:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xltabular}

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\begin{document}
    \renewcommand{\figurename}{Gambar}
    \renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabel}
    
    \title{Penerapan \textit{Convolutional Neural Network} untuk Melakukan Estimasi \textit{Pitch} pada Rekaman Suara Penyanyi\\}
        
    \author{\IEEEauthorblockN{1\textsuperscript{st} Dionisius Pratama}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Faculty of Informatics} \\
    \textit{Institut Teknologi Harapan Bangsa}\\
    Bandung, Indonesia \\
    mail1@mail.com}

    \and
    
    \IEEEauthorblockN{2\textsuperscript{nd} Dr. HH, M.Kom.}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Lecturer of Informatics} \\
    \textit{Institut Teknologi Harapan Bangsa}\\
    Bandung, Indonesia \\
    mail2@mail.com}

    \and
    
    \IEEEauthorblockN{3\textsuperscript{rd} HC, M.T.}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Lecturer of Informatics} \\
    \textit{Institut Teknologi Harapan Bangsa}\\
    Bandung, Indonesia \\
    mail3@mail.com}
    }
    
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

with the output: 
[image: current LaTeX output]

Is there any way that I can make the author section as expected by my uni? What I want to know is whether there are some special syntax to make it like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could just adjust the input to your desired output really. Possibly something like this:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}
    \title{Penerapan \textit{Convolutional Neural Network} untuk Melakukan Estimasi \textit{Pitch} pada Rekaman Suara Penyanyi}
    
    \author{
        \IEEEauthorblockN{Dionisius Pratama\textsuperscript{\#{},1}, HH M. Kom\textsuperscript{\#{},2}, HC, M.T.\textsuperscript{\#{},3}}\\
        \IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Program Studi ...}}\\
        \texttt{
           \textsuperscript{1}mail1@mail.com\\
           \textsuperscript{2}mail1@mail.com\\
           \textsuperscript{3}mail1@mail.com\\
        }
    }
    
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```